# Having trouble with upsells with subscriptions

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I've been having trouble lately trying to find a way to display a subscription product on a one click upsell. Currently I use recharge subscription and reconvert. I reached out to reconvert and upsells/sms by ONE and both said they don't support subscription apps. Could anyone tell me if this is possible or not? Again I'm looking to display a subscription product on a one click upsell post-purchase.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason no one upsells a subscription is probably because at this time anyway, the details of the subscription are complex and require a lot of processing for Shopify. Upsells on the other hand are meant for **mickey D mouse** extras, like selling a cup if you buy a beer.

So either sell your subscription as the goal, and upsell easy widgets, or you're likely not going to be able to deal with subscription upsells unless you roll your own. And since I have rolled my own, I would counsel strongly against that, as the whole empire of Shopify subs is rather, meh at this time.

Comment: Apreciate the answer! I found out that Zippify lets you upsell subscriptions, but now I'm stuck with another problem... I need to to find out if someone bought a product via subscription or a normal purchase, since the app I use lets someone choose when buying the product. It doesn't look like zippify can do that though, unless I can find another method.

Comment: Customer purchase history is always available, and there you could easily find subscription products.

Comment: Unfortunately customer history isn't one of the triggers on zipify, I'm proficient in coding but I lack experience coding on Shopify.

Comment: That is too bad. Zipify is such a dumb name for a service! Serious lack of creative juice there.